# some function applied with ratio never returns

Tags: functional-programming, clojure

can some one please explain why

```
(some #(= 3 %) (range))
```

returns true but

```
(some #(= 4/3 %) (range))
```

never returns?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`(range)`](http://clojure.github.com/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/range) produces an infinite sequence, so it'll just keep looking until it finds a natural number which is equal to 4/3, which isn't terribly likely.